# Restoring .bash_profile in macOS 10.13

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook

I was messing with terminal trying to get Python3 to be the default and used the `nano .bash profile` and now in Terminal, I can't use any of the normal commands such as ping, vim, etc...

This is the PATH settings in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/flake8" export $PATH'
```

I would love to figure out how to get back to the default settings of Terminal in macOS 10.13.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Well, can you share the contents of your `.bash_profile` file in your question so we can see what you have done?

Comment: The default would just be an empty .bash_profile I believe

Comment: @KevinRockwell Not really. I believe there is a single line that sets the PATH and that’s it.

Comment: @JakeGould There isn’t a .bash_profile in the home directory by default in MacOS, it only exists if you create it

Comment: @KevinRockwell Fair enough. Been a long time since I have had to deal with a 100% clean user install on macOS. So good to know!

Comment: After deleting, all seems to be working.  Thank you!

Comment: @user3324136 Happy you solved your issue! But you should always add details like the `PATH` settings in your original question. I now see what the issue is and I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have posted the contents of your `PATH` settings from `.bash_profile` I see the issue. This is your original `PATH` settings line:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/flake8" export $PATH'
```

That makes no sense. That line should begin with `export PATH=` and that extraneous, `export $PATH'` makes less sense; that `export` and `$PATH` with the dollar sign make little sense and that stray single quote doesn’t help; that makes utterly no sense.

Cleaning up what you have should look like this:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/flake8"
```

Save that in your `.bash_profile`, close the Terminal and open a new Terminal session and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that a try.  I really appreciate the help!